# What condition should I put in the if() to count all the positive integers in a array?

Tags: arrays, ruby

Hi I am doing a simple ruby array programming exercise for myself. Everything has gone well until the if statement comes in as I need to count the total value of all positive integer in a array. What should put in the if() condition ?

```
require './input_functions.rb'

def main

arraya = Array.new (10)
num = 5

for x in 0..arraya.length-1
arraya[x] = num
num -=1
end

show(arraya)

puts "Enter a new integer:"
r = gets.chomp.to_i

p = read_integer_in_range("Select an index in the array to store a new integer ", 0, 9)
arraya [p] = r

show(arraya)

sum = 0
for x in 0..arraya.length-1
    if(x > -1)
        sum +=arraya [x]
    end


end

puts "The total of all the positive integers is " + sum.to_s
end

def show (arrayb)
for x in 0..arrayb.length-1
puts arrayb[x]
end
end
main
```

this is the input_function.rb

```
def read_integer_in_range(prompt, min, max)
value = read_integer(prompt)
while (value < min or value > max)
    puts "Please enter a value between " + min.to_s + " and " + max.to_s + ": "
    value = read_integer(prompt);
end
value
end
```

Comment: In ruby we generally don't use for loops instead we would write `arraya.count { |x| x > 0}` or more succinctly `arraya.count(&:positive?)`

Answer (score 0):

ok i figured it out

it is arraya [x] > 0